# Proving $a^{n+1}-1=(a+1)(a^n-1)-a(a^{n-1}-1)$ without induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove the following identity:
>   $$a^{n+1}-1=(a+1)(a^n-1)-a(a^{n-1}-1)$$

By "prove", I mean "prove, not verify" (that is, please do not use mathematical induction).

Comment: This is like asking, "prove $a^2 - 1 = (a-1)(a+1)$"

Comment: Yes. This identity is just showing that the LHS=RHS.

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question.

Comment: Good morning, Now put $ k= a^n$; Just show algebraically  $ ak-1=ak-a+k-1-k+a$

Answer (score 1):

We can check directly that

$$(a+1)(a^n-1)-a(a^{n-1}-1)=a^{n+1}-a+a^n-1-a^n+a=a^{n+1}-1$$

which is a perfectly valid proof.

Comment: Hey, Sorry it was a typo.

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay Yes I've seen that! What do you mean by "I mean proof not verify" and "do not use mathematical induction". We just need to use algebraic rule to check the identity and it is a perfectly allowed and complete proof.

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you mean. I was being naive.